# Memory leaks when returning Tfields from a function

Tags: delphi, memory, memory-leaks

I just have a problem with Delphi that i'm about creating a function in my app and this function is like this

```
function Get_Foundation_infos(): TFields;
begin
  with TMyQuery.Create(nil) do
  begin
    try
      Connection := DataBaseForm.DataBaseForm1.DataBase;
      SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM `foundation_infos` WHERE `Id`=1');
      Execute;
      Result := Fields;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Result := nil;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

the problem is I can't free the `TMyquery` from the out side of the function for that I have a problem of memory leaks and the application stop after 2 or 3 minutes later ....
but if I do free the `TMyquery` Object inside the function, then I can't get the function result from the outside of the function call.

Comment: I'd let whomever using the Fields create and free the query.

Comment: Fields are related with Query for that you can't free the query and use the fields .

Comment: Sertac means that the caller creates the query, then calls your function passing the query object. Then you function forms and executes the query and returns. Then the caller pokes at the fields. Finally, caller destroys query.

Comment: This is not a best practice of using functions , i'll try your methods if any problems i'll return ... thank you gays .

Comment: @Oussaki What is not best practice?

Comment: @Sertac The downside of that is that you cannot guarantee the state of the passed in query object

Comment: @David - The *executer* would raise an exception for the caller to cleanup as in the question. But I guess it's not what you mean perhaps..

Comment: @Sertac I mean that the caller could pass in a soiled object, one that had already been used and was in a bad state. If the function instantiates it, it is known to be clean.

Comment: @David - Ok, I see what you mean.

Comment: Thank you gays i appreciated that ^^ very helpful comments the problem was solved now .

Comment: please use "guys" instead of "gays" or you might be misunderstood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to ensure that the TMyQuery object outlives the TFields object which it owns. But you must also make sure that you destroy that TMyQuery object to avoid the leak.

The simplest way is to return the TMyQuery object from the function and let the caller read the Fields property. When you are done, destroy the TMyQuery object. And naturally you'll use try/finally to ensure that exceptions don't lead to leaks.

```
function CreateFoundationQuery: TMyQuery;
begin
  Result := TMyQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    Result.Connection := DataBaseForm.DataBaseForm1.DataBase;
    Result.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM `foundation_infos` WHERE `Id`=1');
    Result.Execute;
  except
    Result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just find another way maybe when I created an object without referenced it to a variable with a name that the memory manager can't fix the memory leak in this situation for that I created a Variable that have the same Type of function returning and in this case the memory manager can fix any memory leak with this named variable ....

this is the new code of the variable ...

```
function Get_Foundation_infos(): TMyQuery;
var
  q: TMyQuery;
begin
  q := TMyQuery.Create(nil);

  with q do

  begin

    try

      Connection := DataBaseForm.DataBaseForm1.DataBase;

      SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM `foundation_infos` WHERE `Id`=1');
      Execute;

      Result := q;

    except
      on E: Exception do
        Result := nil;
    end;

  end;

end;
```

Comment: That's the same as my answer, except your code leaks when exception raised after query is created.

Comment: Yeah i have to call the free; when exception raised .

Comment: @David: And this code uses an unnecessary `q` variable that yours doesn't.

Comment: And the function should start with `Create` following a useful convention to indicate to the owner that he is responsible for destroying that object.